# Getting Schema Information for the databse failed with the exception 500 is the max tables azure data sync problem

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Error : Getting Schema Information for the database failed with the exception unable to process a schema with 2434 500

Database Sync Group error on Azure syncing local offline server.

What's the best way to sync offline database even if it's not this way

Answer (score 1):

Please reference the Data Sync [Limitations on service and database dimensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#limitations-on-service-and-database-dimensions):

[image]

I agree with @Alberto Morillo, your exception should be "Unable to process a schema with 2434 tables, 500 is the max....".

Here's the Azure official blog talk about how to [Sync SQL data in large scale using Azure SQL Data Sync](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-mx/blog/sync-sql-data-in-large-scale-using-azure-sql-data-sync/). It gives you a solution to solve the exception:

**Sync data between databases with many tables**

Currently, data sync can only sync between databases with less than 500 tables. You can work around this limitation by creating multiple sync groups using different database users. For example, you want to sync two databases with 900 tables. First, you need to define two different users in the database where you load the sync schema from. Each user can only see 450 (or any number less than 500) tables in the database. Sync setup requires ALTER DATABASE permission which implies CONTROL permission over all tables so you will need to explicitly DENY the permissions on tables which you don’t want a specific user to see, instead of using GRANT. You can find the exact privilege needed for sync initialization in the [best practice guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-best-practices-data-sync). Then you can create two sync groups, one for each user. Each sync group will sync 450 tables between these two databases. Since each user can only see less than 500 tables, you will be able to load the schema and create sync groups! After the sync group is created and initialized, we recommend you follow the [best practice guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-best-practices-data-sync) to update the user permission and make sure they have the minimum privilege for ongoing sync.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leon Yue for the detailed answer. We decided to sync the two SQL servers directly via https. instead of using Azure Sql.

Answer (score 0):

The full error message you are receiving may look like "Getting schema information for the database failed with the exception "Unable to process a schema with 2434 tables, 500 is the max.  For more information, provide tracing ID '8d609598-3dsf-45ae-93v7-04ab21e45f6f' to customer support."

It is a current limitation on SQL Data Sync that if the database has more than 500 tables, it does not get the schema for you to select the tables - even if you want to select and sync only 1 table.

A workaround for you is to delete the extra tables or move the un-needed tables into another DB. Not ideal, we agree, but is a workaround for now. To try the workaround perform the following steps.

1. Script the tables you want to sync(less than 500 tables per synchronization group)
2. Create a new temporary database and run the script to create the tables you want to sync
3. Register and add the new temporary database as a member of the sync group
4. Use the new temporary database to pick the tables you want to sync
5. Add all other databases that you want to sync with (on-premise databases
   and hub database)
6. Once the provisioning is done, remove the temporary database from the sync group.

Comment: Hey Alberto Morillo. 
Thanks for the detailed and quick response. we are afraid of data loss to make that happen. we decided to install Sql server into the VM and Sync between the two SQL servers directly via Https. Then we will be using the Sql server on the online server to feed Nav Dynamics.Instead using Azure Sql server. Would love to have your input on that route. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could be managed using following steps (I have used limited tables steps, as I was only targeting 400 tables for my requirement):

- If you are looking for limited tables only

Create a user at your on-prem sql server, with limited tables right. i.e. GRANT SELECT ON databasename.table_name to username; (Add multiple tables which needs to be synced)

Once this is done, register this user at SQL Data Sync application at your On-Prem server

[SQL Data Sync image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF3gm.jpg)

and select this at your Database Sync Group at Azure (Add an On-Premises Database).

[Database Sync Group image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntKMp.png)

You'll be able to see all tables you granted permission at your On-Prem DB

- If you are looking for all tables

Create multiple users with 500 tables each user, and create multiple sync groups using these different database users.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this limitation by using features of SQL server and I share my experience here so others may try this path.

First, the limit of 500 tables is a hard limit, creating multiple share groups and other advise regularly fails because the initial "Refresh Schema" dialog fails to load before one can deselect some tables.

Scenario: I want to connect to an OnPrem SQL Server, readonly, and sync data  partially into an Azure SQL Database instance. I'm using Azure SQL Data Sync because the setup is easy and it's much cheaper that Azure Data Fabric, for instance. Also, I can't and won't extend or change the OnPrem database or do any work on the existing (production) instance. However, bi-directional sync may work (I don't do this right now).

### Preparation

Steps to create a replica of an existing DB:

1. Create a new instance on your OnPrem SQL Server
2. Create a new Database on this instance
3. Link the existing OnPrem SQL database

- In SSMS go to "Server Objects" > "Linked Servers" > "Add New Linked Server"
- Fill in the servers name, NAME\INSTANCE
- Go to tab "Security" and enter credentials for your OnPrem server

4. Once the link is established create views on this linked server

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[OnPremRefTable] AS SELECT * FROM [ONPREMSRV\ONPREMINSTANCE].[ONPREMDB].[dbo].OnPremTable;
```

Note, that naming is crucial here. **Don't name your linked table the same name as the OnPrem table.** The Azure SQL Data Sync can't read views, it can just read tables. But if a view with the name "TableA" exists, you can't create a table with the name "TableA". So, I create my views with a prefix, say "opdb".

If the name of the table is "TableA", the statement looks like this

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[opdbTableA] AS SELECT * FROM [ONPREMSRV\ONPREMINSTANCE].[ONPREMDB].[dbo].TableA;
```

Now, to expose this we need real tables. These tables are named *exactly* as in the OnPrem db and they just reference the views.

```
SELECT *
INTO [dbo].[TableA]
FROM [dbo].[opdbTableA];
```

> Very important. If you strip the columns by naming them instead of using * assure you keep the primary key. Sync won't work without a PK.

In case you forgot of the key column is not recognized as PK, add a key:

```
-- Add a new column to act as a Primary Key (only if missing !!)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourTableName] ADD [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;

-- Define the (new) column as the Primary Key
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
```

The name "ID" is just an example, can by any name.

### Add Sync

Now, download and install the Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0 tool. Follow the instruction from Microsoft to create the key and connect to the new database in the new instance.

The Refresh Schema dialog now sees the limited database with just few tables you really need and the data are "linked", that means they are always current and don't need syncing between the instances.

[image: All steps in SSMS]

### Refresh Your Data

The created tables do not reflect live data. Just run a scheduled job, ideally ahead of the sync timer. So, if Azure Sync runs at 8am daily, then you schedule the sync 7.30am daily.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RefreshDataFromView
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Assuming @LinkedServerView is your linked server view and @LocalTable is your local table

    -- 1. Pull new records
    INSERT INTO dbo.LocalTable (Id, [Name], ...)
    SELECT Id, [Name], ...
    FROM dbo.LinkedServerView
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.LocalTable);

    -- 2. Delete records that no longer exist in the source
    DELETE lt
    FROM dbo.LocalTable lt
    LEFT JOIN dbo.LinkedServerView v ON lt.ID = v.ID
    WHERE v.ID IS NULL;

    -- 3. Update changed records
    UPDATE lt
    SET 
        lt.[Name] = v.[Name],
        ... 
    FROM dbo.Patient lt
    INNER JOIN dbo.X2Patient v ON lt.ID = v.ID
    WHERE 
        lt.[Name] != v.[Name] OR
        ...

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
GO
```

"..." indicates more columns.

#### Schedule a Job using SQL Server Agent

Use SQL Server Agent to create a job that runs this stored procedure at the intervals you require.

- Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
- Connect to your Database Engine.
- Expand SQL Server Agent.
- Right-click on Jobs and select "New Job".
- In the New Job dialog, give your job a name and then define the steps (you would add a step that runs your stored procedure).
- Define the schedule for when you want the job to run (e.g., daily, hourly, every few minutes, depending on your needs and the impact on performance).